# "this class" in generic methods?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I'm still figuring out generic methods and signatures, and I suspect this is an FAQ, but...

I have a base class called DtaRow that consists primarily of a List(Of String). I have several subclasses of DtaRow with additional *methods*, no other changes. So we have a DateRow with a method called TheDate that takes an item from the List and returns a DateTime based on that string. We have another class called NumberRow with a TheNumber that picks a different item from the List and Double.Parses it to a Double. Etc.

I would like to have a method that returns a deep copy of the *Row. As all of the data is identical between all of these classes, you can write a single method to do this in DtaRow. However, it can only return a DtaRow, which loses the methods. So I did this...

```
Friend Function CopyTo(Of T As DtaRow)(Optional ByVal ParentIn As DtaTable = Nothing) As T
```

To call this method I have to do this...

```
Dim TD As DateRow = TempD.CopyTo(Of DateRow)
```

It appears that this doesn't help, because I still have "a cast" in the line, which is precisely what I would like to avoid. Is there a way to write this without the (Of T as DtaRow), is there a syntax along the lines of (Of T as WhatEverClassImBeingCalledOn), or some way to do that without the type input at all?

Comment: you could change it to have multiple methods `CopyToDateRow`, `CopyToNumberRow` etc.  If it aint broke, dont fix it.

Comment: Each of those methods would be 100% identical, which seems like precisely the sort of thing we want to avoid.

Comment: Ok, then how is a DateRow different from a NumberRow that you need an `(Of T)` method?  You could return a `DtaRow` and cast the return but `As T` seems simpler to me

Comment: Changes to original question to clarify(?).

Comment: `WhatEverClassImBeingCalledOn` isnt the point to copy to a *different* dta type?  how would the Type invoking the call tell you what the desired return Type is?

Comment: Uh, no, the point is to make a deep copy of one, say, DateRow into another DateRow. Dim D As DateRow = SomeOtherDateRow.CopyTo() It would seem the type system knows what class SomeOtherDateRow is because it complains if I put any other type there!

Comment: I'm sorry, all this talk about generics I thought you wanted to convert.  To copy one, you just need a copy constructor or the serialize trick if there are oodles of properties

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .Net variant of the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Given these classes:

```
MustInherit Class DtaRow(Of T As {DtaRow(Of T), New})

    Function Copy() As T
        Return new T()
    End Function

End Class

Class DateRow 
    Inherits DtaRow(of DateRow)

End Class
```

calling `Copy` on a subclass of `DtaRow` returns an object of the correct type:

```
Dim dt = new DateRow()
Dim copy = dt.Copy()
Debug.Assert(copy.GetType() = GetType(DateRow))
```

The obvious drawbacks:

- `DtaRow` has to be generic
- You could mess up the generic type argument in a subclass

But there's no other way to tell a method in  `DtaRow` to return an object of the type of a child class.

If you don't want to make `DtaRow`, you'll have to implement a method in each child class (which could simply call a `Copy` method of `DtaRow` can just cast it to their own type).